# CSS border overlap

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am applying a simple style to a complex layout:

```
* {
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

It works but causes all sort of additional borders. Is there a way to remove or collapse additional borders globally as I do not (nor can I) know what divs or other elements will touch???

Is there a jQuery plugin which will apply a simple border to all elements, taking this requirement into consideration?

---

#### EDIT :

I realize the star is a wildcard that is the effect I am after but I don't want borders to double-up or triple up

When two tandem DIV's have border defined - the center border will be a width of two - I want it to actually overlap so it's rendered as only 1px not 2 px. I cannot know what elements will have this so manually applying the styles or removing the them on a case by case basis is not acceptable.

Comment: If you don't want a border on all your elements, then don't apply a border to all your elements.

Comment: You are saying to browsers: *Apply a border of 1px solid #eaeaea to **all elements** in the page*. The way to remove additional borders doesn't exists, simply apply the borders to the elements you need, not all.

Comment: Look this: [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836251/avoid-border-overlap-css)

Comment: You are applying this to everything so it makes sense that it creates additional borders. If you don't want every element to have a border then apply this only to only the ones you want.

Comment: I am not sure how else I can explain my requirements. I want a border on all elements...except in the case where the element above, below or to the sides has already rendered a border. I thought CSS might have some feature like table border-collapsing - but I guess not.

I cannot know what elements will or will not have already rendered borders either - I need this CSS solution to work on arbitrary HTML that I did not write

Answer (score 1):

You could do this :

```
* {
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.no-border {
    border: none;
}
```

Then, attach the class `no-border` to all elements that should not have a border.

---

#### Note :

I don't think it's a great idea to set a border for all elements by default, but this technique should give you what you want.

Comment: I agree with your final note. The best way is the opposite, apply only the border to the elements you want, not reverse. My upvote to you only for the final note :)

Answer (score 0):

`*` means all, use `!important` after your css statement but before the ';'

or apply a class to elements you want it to be to and still include the '!important'

Comment: I realize that - but I want the border applied to every element (think wireframe) except those which already have a border - in which case the border about to be rendered would collapse into the existing border - as tables would do.

Comment: use JavaScript to get all, include a where clause and apply your css, the if statement can have the with and without possibility so then it will apply to both, make sure to replace existing with the !important

Comment: So basically there is no CSS solution nor is there an existing jQuery plugin which achieves my goal?

Comment: css, whith javascript to determine an elements state, even do a $('myel).each(function(){)

Comment: Ideally I won't re-invent the wheel - hence the is there an existing jQuery plugin? I could use jQuery but how do I handle responsive designs? Does jQuery tell me when a DIV has collapsed into vertical layout when browser window resized?

Comment: bootstrap3 my firend

Comment: I am using B3 - how do I achieve this? :)

Comment: as i said, no other way

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for avoid elements side by side having the sum of 2 borders, they should collapse instead.

Here is one way you can do to fix that.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.row1 ~ div.row1 {
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
}

div.row2 {
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
}

div.row2 ~ div.row2 {
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1"></div>
<div class="row1"></div>
<div class="row1"></div>
<div class="row2"></div>
<div class="row2"></div>
<div class="row2"></div>
```

Collapsing borders also are supported natively by `table`'s using the property `border-collapse: collapse`

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

A third way would be to use negative margin

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.row1 ~ div.row1 {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

div.row2 {
  margin-top: -1px;
}

div.row2 ~ div.row2 {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1"></div>
<div class="row1"></div>
<div class="row1"></div>
<div class="row2"></div>
<div class="row2"></div>
<div class="row2"></div>
```